# Source kit service terminated Editor functionality temporarily limited

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I recently started working on swift.
While i am doing , i got a alert message says Source kit service terminated Editor functionality temporarily limited.

I quit the xcode and reopens also, but not works.

The whole text mode also changes to black colour.

Do i need to update any thing, please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The list of topics is here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Early release software is not listed as off topic.